# How to render variable components in vue like jsx?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In jsx we can store components in variables like `const comp=<p>Hello</p>` and then we can put these variables anywhere, choosing witch component to render.

I was wondering if there is a similar thing in vue. If I had a template like:

```
<template>
  <variable-comp />
</template>
```

I would like to change what variable-comp is dynamically. I'm aware of `v-if` and `v-for` but that's not the same thing.

Comment: there is one webpack plugin for vuejs https://github.com/vuejs/jsx. With this plugin you can use jsx in your render method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vue uses this syntax for dynamic components

```js
<component v-bind:is=”currentComponent”/>
```

where 'currentComponent' is the name (string) of component.

i.e.

```html
<template>
  <component v-bind:is=”currentComponent”/>
</template>
```

```js
import CompA from './CompA.vue'
import CompB from './CompB.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    CompA,
    CompB
  },
  data() {
    isA: true
  },
  computed: {
    currentComponent() {
      return isA ? 'CompA' : 'CompB'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also define the html directly in the Components, but if it's really just a <p> tag, it's best to write it directly in the Templates above. Or use vue and jsx: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

Comment: Actually, the question came in my mind because I had a hundred SVG icons that I needed to change, and I knew I could import them as VUE components, but I could not change it dynamically, so I rendered them as HTML. But sometimes it is better to change components.

Comment: is the SVG icon going to be referenced from an img tag? You could create a JS object mapping the icons and just pop them into the `src` attribute as needed, rather than using a component?